# ffmpeg get the audio stream from mp4 and send it to speech recognition

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, mp4

I have few .mp4 video files in which at the start of each video file there is a word, I want to load these files get the audio check what is the spoken word and rename the file accordingly.

Currently what i am doing is, converting all the mp4 files to wav and then sending the to speech recognition and then doing the renaming stuff.

Is there a way to cut short the "converting to wav" part out and directly send the mp4 audio stream to speech recognition ??

Thanks,

Comment: You can [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) selected segments with ffmpeg.

Comment: I am real newbie to this can you show an example on how to do it, a sample / pseudo code

Comment: I'm not an API user, but did you see the examples in `doc/examples/`?

Comment: After researching a bit here and there i got a way to get the stream directly

Comment: You can provide a sample code as an answer here to help others if they are looking to do something similar.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : Now I got the stream from ffmpeg, but stuck with another issue. I dont think the data I am getting it correct. I tried reading the byte array and sending it to the SoundPlayer class in order to play the sound, but it gives me Error  "The Wave header is Corrupt."